# MS Project Server 2010 and Oracle Database Backend?

Tags: windows, database, oracle, microsoft-project

After searching far and wide across the internet for an answer I have come here in hope of help.  I am aware that MS Project Server 2010 requires a SharePoint server, but does anyone know if it is possible to run Project Server utilizing an Oracle database instead of SQL?

Comment: Why would you want to use an Oracle back end in the first place?

Comment: Have you asked Microsoft? My inclination is the answer will be a resounding **NO**, possibly with a "…but if you want to buy SQL Server 2013…" thrown in at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this Microsoft document](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee683978.aspx#section8), Project Server 2010 requires MSSQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

There are exactly ZERO Microsoft products that work with Oracle. Not a single one.

Comment: What about Oracle ODBC drivers for Windows?

Comment: ODBC will allow an application to connect to Oracle without using the Oracle native client, but it doesn't do anything to remove the explicit dependencies an application may have for SQL Server. If an application wasn't designed to support Oracle on the backend, no amount of ODBC magic will help.